# (Note 8) Is there a way to hide the voice recorder files from the media folder but still display them in the voice recorder app?

Tags: samsung-galaxy-note-8

by default the voice recorder sound files show up in the media folder. I feel like they shoulnd't be displayed there. This is not a problem for the music player app, but I want things tidy. When I try to hide them with a .nomedia file, they don't show up in the voice recorder app.
Is there another way to hide them and still have them displaying in the stock voice recorder?

Comment: Well the music player is not the problem but I was hoping I could keep the folders more tidy. Without stuff showing up where it's not supposed to

Comment: OK I understand. Thanks for that clarification!

Comment: Ok I simply solved my problem by deinstalling the standart audio recorder and installing one that can handle nomedia folders. I thought it was one of those undeleteable stock apps but it wasn't.

Comment: Good in which case you can self answer